# E/Ads: Fail to get isAdIdFakeForDebugLogging with error code 3

Tags: android, admob, apk, ads, ioexception

The ads in my app was work normally yesterday in debug mode but today I got this error

```
2019-04-06 05:08:47.412 12191-12286/www.pro_cs_is.com E/Ads: Fail to get isAdIdFakeForDebugLogging
    java.io.IOException: Connection failure
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:68)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.d.d_(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-04-06 05:08:48.772 12191-12191/www.pro_cs_is.com E/AD ERROR: error code3
2019-04-06 05:09:04.314 12191-12191/www.pro_cs_is.com E/AD ERROR: error code3
2019-04-06 05:09:08.344 12191-12191/www.pro_cs_is.com E/AD ERROR: error code3
```

**manifest meta-data**

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/ADMOB_APP_ID"/>
```

**MainActivity ad xml**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/mainActivityBanner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/MainActivityBanner"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I tried ads units test and its working but my unites is not

Comment: Your app is live in play store?

Comment: @Hardik Talaviya not yet

Comment: So,you can not show your live ads only show testing ads using test id.if you want to show live ads add your app in play store.

Comment: @Hardik Talaviya the ads was working yesterday, and also I didn't got this exception before `java.io.IOException`

Comment: show your java code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after I [posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/-SIX2Xbbd7c) on group **Google Mobile Ads SDK Technical Forum** they replied with

> "I suggest to load test ads instead of live ads to avoid invalid activities. You may do this with your live Ad Unit ID and enabling test device.
>   The error code 3 that you encountered means that an ad request is successful but it can't return ads due to lack of ad inventory. Also, please note that that loading your Ad Unit IDs on an unpublished app may have an impact fill rate."

and after I published the app the ads showed successfully

Comment: What is "ads inventory"?

Comment: @HX_unbanned it means available ads on admob server